# How to display all LSTM states in Keras summary?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, state, lstm, summary

When using the keras feature `model.summary()` it shows me the tensor shapes of my model which is very nice!
Unfortunately, when using a encoder LSTM, called with the `keras.layers.LSTM` constructor with the property `return_states=True`, the summary is not displayed in its full form. It looks something like this:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input (InputLayer)              (None, 34, 30)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder (LSTM)                  [(None, 34, 30), (No 7320        input[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_8 (Lambda)               (None, 34, 15)       0           encoder[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder (LSTM)                  (None, 34, 30)       5520        lambda_8[0][0]                   
                                                                 encoder[0][1]                    
                                                                 encoder[0][2]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 12,840
Trainable params: 12,840
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

As you can see the output shape of the encoder is cut off and only the first of the three shapes is visible. Is there a way to display it, maybe a fix or even a workaround? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```
print(encoder.output_shape)
>> [(None, 34, 30), (None, 30), (None, 30)]
```